# How do you test model field types in Django?

Tags: python, sql, django, database, testing

I'm trying to test whether a field is in fact a primary key.

```
class PatientTests(test.TestCase):
    def test_primary_key(self):
        # Cannot be NULL
        patient = models.Patients(patient_id=None)
        patient.save()
```

But the test is passing with no exceptions raised.

My model definition:

```
class Patients(models.Model):
    patient_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, primary_key=True)
```

Using Django version 3.0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `MyModel._meta.pk.name` will give you the name of the `primary key`

Comment: True true, now how do I prove that primary key will not accept NULL values using a simple test case?

Comment: `print(patient._meta.pk.name)` gives `patient_id` so that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason your code causes Django to save the object with the primary key set to empty string `''`. In the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#null), it is stated that Django's convention is to use an empty string as null.

[As they say](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9590), it is by design and documented. Furthermore, [they have stated that](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3774) `primary_key=True` does not imply `blank=False`, `null=False` and `unique=True`, nevertheless when I added `null=False` it didn't help and again the test passed. I think it would be an issue or at least undefined behavior with Django.

Comment: No no, `Primary_key=True implies null=False and unique=True`  Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/ (updated documentation)


So why is it allowing null values to be saved?

Comment: @NoName are you sure you're using Django 3.0? However, please update your question mentioning your Django version.

Comment: I added it, I think Django is doing something behind to scenes to actively prevent inserting NULL values to primary keys. Not sure.

Comment: I hope someone from the community answers this question.